# How do I add 1 day to an NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, swift, date, cocoa-touch, nsdate

Basically, as the title says. I'm wondering how I could add 1 day to an `NSDate`.

So if it were:

```
21st February 2011
```

It would become:

```
22nd February 2011
```

Or if it were:

```
31st December 2011
```

It would become:

```
1st January 2012.
```

Comment: Note that an NSDate does not represent a date, it represents a point in time. So it includes a time as well as a date.

Comment: Agreed - you should be using Zack German's answer below. See Apple's [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW3).

Answer (score 778):

**Swift 5.0 :**

```
var dayComponent    = DateComponents()
dayComponent.day    = 1 // For removing one day (yesterday): -1
let theCalendar     = Calendar.current
let nextDate        = theCalendar.date(byAdding: dayComponent, to: Date())
print("nextDate : \(nextDate)")
```

**Objective C :**

```
NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dayComponent.day = 1;

NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *nextDate = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

NSLog(@"nextDate: %@ ...", nextDate);
```

This should be self-explanatory.

Comment: You can also use negative components to subtract from a date.

Comment: Much better solution than the selected answer

Comment: +1 for using Date components rather than adding a day's worth of seconds.

Comment: Yes works well for daylight savings. Tip for DST check: Reset date and time on your mac and then restart your simulator, it will then follow your system time.

Comment: Be sure to set the required timeZone on theCalendar if you're working in anything other than default system time zone.

Comment: In Swift you need to change the last parameter of the `dateByAddingComponents ` call to `NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0)`

Comment: not working in case if i add one day in 28 Feb 2016 it convert it to 1 March 2016, as it is leap year it should be 29 Feb 2016

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - considering the post is tagged as objective c

Answer (score 285):

Since iOS 8 you can use `NSCalendar.dateByAddingUnit`

Example in Swift 1.x:

```
let today = NSDate()
let tomorrow = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    .dateByAddingUnit(
         .CalendarUnitDay, 
         value: 1, 
         toDate: today, 
         options: NSCalendarOptions(0)
    )
```

Swift 2.0:

```
let today = NSDate()
let tomorrow = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    .dateByAddingUnit(
        .Day, 
        value: 1, 
        toDate: today, 
        options: []
    )
```

Swift 3.0:

```
let today = Date()
let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: today)
```

Comment: Is it just me, or wouldn't it be much simpler for Swift to have something built in like `date.add(.days, 1)` ? *goes and builds an extension

Comment: @quemeful `extension Date {
    func adding(_ component: Calendar.Component, _ value: Int) -> Date? {
        return  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: component, value: value, to: self)
    }
}` usage `Date().adding(.day, 1)  // "Jun 6, 2019 at 5:35 PM"`

Answer (score 131):

**Swift 5**

```
let today = Date()
let nextDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: today)
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
// now build a NSDate object for the next day
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setDay:1];
NSDate *nextDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate: [NSDate date] options:0];
```

Answer (score 39):

A working **Swift 3+ implementation** based on [highmaintenance's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351305/highmaintenance) answer and [vikingosegundo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106435/vikingosegundo) comment. This Date extension also has additional options to change year, month and time:

```
extension Date {

    /// Returns a Date with the specified amount of components added to the one it is called with
    func add(years: Int = 0, months: Int = 0, days: Int = 0, hours: Int = 0, minutes: Int = 0, seconds: Int = 0) -> Date? {
        let components = DateComponents(year: years, month: months, day: days, hour: hours, minute: minutes, second: seconds)
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: self)
    }

    /// Returns a Date with the specified amount of components subtracted from the one it is called with
    func subtract(years: Int = 0, months: Int = 0, days: Int = 0, hours: Int = 0, minutes: Int = 0, seconds: Int = 0) -> Date? {
        return add(years: -years, months: -months, days: -days, hours: -hours, minutes: -minutes, seconds: -seconds)
    }

}
```

Usage for only adding a day as asked by OP would then be:

```
let today = Date() // date is then today for this example
let tomorrow = today.add(days: 1)
```

Comment: You could shorten the code massively by using date components.

Comment: You're right, although it has downsides in my opinion:
- the code using the extension doesn't look as clean
- it opens up some unnecessary options with components that make little sense like `let foo = Date().add([.calendar: 1, .yearForWeekOfYear: 3]`

I'm adding the alternative solution to my answer though. Thanks for your suggestion, @vikingosegundo!

Comment: well, I actually meant something different: https://gist.github.com/vikingosegundo/31ddb14920415ef444a9ab550411d4ff

Answer (score 38):

iOS 8+, OSX 10.9+, Objective-C

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];    
NSDate *tomorrow = [cal dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay 
                                   value:1 
                                  toDate:[NSDate date] 
                                 options:0];
```

Comment: Note that you can't mask the unit here (use only one).

Answer (score 27):

**Swift 4.0** (same as Swift 3.0 in [this wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27048988/1296746) just making it clear for rookies like me)

```
let today = Date()
let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: today)
```

Comment: Did you forget to change your variable name?

Answer (score 16):

Update for Swift 4:

```swift
let now = Date() // the current date/time
let oneDayFromNow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: now) // Tomorrow with same time of day as now
```

Answer (score 15):

Use the below function and use days paramater to get the date daysAhead/daysBehind just pass parameter as positive for future date or negative for previous dates:

```
+ (NSDate *) getDate:(NSDate *)fromDate daysAhead:(NSUInteger)days
{
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dateComponents.day = days;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *previousDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents
                                                     toDate:fromDate
                                                    options:0];
    [dateComponents release];
    return previousDate;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

In swift

```
var dayComponenet = NSDateComponents()
dayComponenet.day = 1

var theCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
var nextDate = theCalendar.dateByAddingComponents(dayComponenet, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil)
```

Answer (score 11):

It works!

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSCalendarUnit unit = NSCalendarUnitDay;
NSInteger value = 1;
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *tomorrow = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:unit value:value toDate:today options:NSCalendarMatchStrictly];
```

Comment: my answer is more correct because if you use NSCalendarWrapComponents(0) option you can create date only in the range of current month. It means that if you add 1 day with NSCalendarWrapComponents to Jan,31 2016 you will get Jan,1 2016. With NSCalendarMatchStrictly option you will get next calendar date.

Answer (score 10):

Swift 3.0 very simple implementation would be:

```
func dateByAddingDays(inDays: Int) -> Date {
    let today = Date()
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: inDays, to: today)!
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4.0**

```
extension Date {
    func add(_ unit: Calendar.Component, value: Int) -> Date? {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: unit, value: value, to: self)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
date.add(.day, 3)!   // adds 3 days
date.add(.day, -14)!   // subtracts 14 days
```

*Note: If you don't know why the lines of code end with an exclamation point, look up "Swift Optionals" on Google.*

Answer (score 7):

```
NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.day=1;
NSDate *targetDate =[calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:today options: 0];
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple Swift extensions for yesterday and tomorrow from any date:

```
extension Date {
    
    var previousDay: Date {
        Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day:-1), to: self)!
    }
    
    var nextDay: Date {
        Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day:+1), to: self)!
    }
    
}
```

I'm force unwrapping the optionals based on advice in the question here:
[When does dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options return nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358131/when-does-datebyaddingcomponentstodateoptions-return-nil)

Answer (score 5):

```
NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
dayComponent.day = 1;

NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
dateToBeIncremented = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:dateToBeIncremented options:0];
```

Ok - I thought this was going to work for me. However, if you use it to add a day to the 31st March 2013, it'll return a date that has only 23 hours added to it. It may well actually have the 24, but using in calculations has only 23:00 hours added.

Similarly, if you blast forward to 28th Oct 2013, the code adds 25 hours resulting in a date time of 2013-10-28 01:00:00.

In order to add a day I was doing the thing at the top, adding the:

```
NSDate *newDate1 = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];
```

Complicated, principally due to daylight saving.

Comment: once a year a day has just 23 hours. once 25. and every few years it has the length of `60*60*24 + 1` because of leap seconds. dates must cover all of this, and that is why the date handling of cocoa actually is great!

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 2.1.1 and xcode 7.1 OSX 10.10.5 ,you can add any number of days forward and backwards using function

```
func addDaystoGivenDate(baseDate:NSDate,NumberOfDaysToAdd:Int)->NSDate
{
    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    let CurrentCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let CalendarOption = NSCalendarOptions()

    dateComponents.day = NumberOfDaysToAdd

    let newDate = CurrentCalendar.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: baseDate, options: CalendarOption)
    return newDate!
}
```

function call for incrementing current date by 9 days

```
var newDate = addDaystoGivenDate(NSDate(), NumberOfDaysToAdd: 9)
print(newDate)
```

function call for decrement current date by 80 days

```
newDate = addDaystoGivenDate(NSDate(), NumberOfDaysToAdd: -80)
 print(newDate)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a general purpose method which lets you add/subtract any type of unit(Year/Month/Day/Hour/Second etc) in the specified date.

Using **Swift 2.2**

```
func addUnitToDate(unitType: NSCalendarUnit, number: Int, date:NSDate) -> NSDate {

    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
        unitType,
        value: number,
        toDate: date,
        options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!

}

print( addUnitToDate(.Day, number: 1, date: NSDate()) ) // Adds 1 Day To Current Date
print( addUnitToDate(.Hour, number: 1, date: NSDate()) ) // Adds 1 Hour To Current Date
print( addUnitToDate(.Minute, number: 1, date: NSDate()) ) // Adds 1 Minute To Current Date

// NOTE: You can use negative values to get backward values too
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use NSDate's method `- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds` where `seconds` would be `60 * 60 * 24 = 86400`

Comment: NSDate's addByTimeInterval was deprecated in iOS 4 (http://bit.ly/vtOzvU). Use dateByAddingTimeInterval (http://bit.ly/vRkFrN) instead.

Comment: days can have 23, 24 or 25 hours, because of daylight saving times.

Answer (score 4):

In swift you can make extension to add method in NSDate

```
extension NSDate {
    func addNoOfDays(noOfDays:Int) -> NSDate! {
        let cal:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        cal.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
        let comps:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
        comps.day = noOfDays
        return cal.dateByAddingComponents(comps, toDate: self, options: nil)
    }
}
```

you can use this as

```
NSDate().addNoOfDays(3)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
int daysToAdd = 1;
NSDate *tomorrowDate = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMM yyyy"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:tomorrowDate]);
```

Comment: who ever uses this code and runs in trouble: well deserved

Answer (score 3):

for swift 2.2:

```
let today = NSDate()
let tomorrow = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
        .Day,
        value: 1,
        toDate: today,
        options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchStrictly)
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

update for swift 5

```
let nextDate = fromDate.addingTimeInterval(60*60*24)
```

Comment: Don't ever adjust dates using TimeInterval unless you specifically want a number of seconds. This will not work if you are dealing with changes to daylight savings, leap seconds, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
NSDate *startDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"StartDate = %@", startDate);

components.day += 1;
NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"EndDate = %@", endDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem; use an extension for NSDate:

```
- (id)dateByAddingYears:(NSUInteger)years
                 months:(NSUInteger)months
                   days:(NSUInteger)days
                  hours:(NSUInteger)hours
                minutes:(NSUInteger)minutes
                seconds:(NSUInteger)seconds
{
    NSDateComponents * delta = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSCalendar * gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc]
                               initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian] autorelease];

    [delta setYear:years];
    [delta setMonth:months];
    [delta setDay:days];
    [delta setHour:hours];
    [delta setMinute:minutes];
    [delta setSecond:seconds];

    return [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:delta toDate:self options:0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.0

```
let today = NSDate()    
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let tomorrow = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: today, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchFirst)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4, if all you really need is a 24 hour shift (60*60*24 seconds) and not "1 calendar day"

Future:
`let dayAhead = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(86400.0))`

Past:
`let dayAgo = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(-86400.0))`

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4 or Swift 5, you can use like bellow:

```
let date = Date()
let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: date)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let yesterday_date = dateFormatter.string(from: yesterday!)
print("yesterday->",yesterday_date)
```

output:

```
Current date: 2020-03-02
yesterday date: 2020-03-01
```

Answer (score 2):

String extension: Convert **String_Date > Date**

```
extension String{
  func DateConvert(oldFormat:String)->Date{ // format example: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 
    let isoDate = self
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale to reliable US_POSIX
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = oldFormat
    return dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate)!
  }
}
```

Date extension: Convert **Date > String**

```
extension Date{
 func DateConvert(_ newFormat:String)-> String{
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = newFormat
    return formatter.string(from: self)
 }
}
```

Date extension:  **Get +/- Date**

```
extension String{
  func next(day:Int)->Date{
    var dayComponent    = DateComponents()
    dayComponent.day    = day
    let theCalendar     = Calendar.current
    let nextDate        = theCalendar.date(byAdding: dayComponent, to: Date())
    return nextDate!
  }

 func past(day:Int)->Date{
    var pastCount = day
    if(pastCount>0){
        pastCount = day * -1
    }
    var dayComponent    = DateComponents()
    dayComponent.day    = pastCount
    let theCalendar     = Calendar.current
    let nextDate        = theCalendar.date(byAdding: dayComponent, to: Date())
    return nextDate!
 }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let today = Date()
let todayString = "2020-02-02 23:00:00"
let newDate = today.DateConvert("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") //2020-02-02 23:00:00
let newToday = todayString.DateConvert(oldFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")//2020-02-02
let newDatePlus = today.next(day: 1)//2020-02-03 23:00:00
let newDateMinus = today.past(day: 1)//2020-02-01 23:00:00
```

reference: from multiple question

[How do I add 1 day to an NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-an-nsdate)

[math function to convert positive int to negative and negative to positive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869911/java-math-function-to-convert-positive-int-to-negative-and-negative-to-positive)

[Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, with a few extensions and operator overloads, you can end up with something nice, like:

```swift
let today = Date()
let tomorrow = today + 1.days
```

, or

```swift
var date = Date()
date += 1.months
```

Below is the support code:

```swift
extension Calendar {
    struct ComponentWithValue {
        let component: Component
        let value: Int
    }
}

extension Int {
    var days: Calendar.ComponentWithValue {
        .init(component: .day, value: self)
    }
    
    var months: Calendar.ComponentWithValue {
        .init(component: .month, value: self)
    }
}

func +(_ date: Date, _ amount: Calendar.ComponentWithValue) -> Date {
    Calendar.current.date(byAdding: amount.component, value: amount.value, to: date)!
}

func +(_ amount: Calendar.ComponentWithValue, _ date: Date) -> Date {
    date + amount
}

func +=(_ date: inout Date, _ amount: Calendar.ComponentWithValue) {
    date = date + amount
}
```

The code is minimal, and can be easily extended to allow `.months`, `.years`, `.hours`, etc. Also support for subtraction (`-`) can be seamlessly added.

There is a forced unwrap, though, within the implementation of the `+` operator, however not sure under which circumstances can the calendar return a nil date.

Answer (score -2):

Use following code:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
int daysToAdd = 1;
NSDate *newDate1 = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];
```

As

```
addTimeInterval
```

is now deprecated.

Comment: days can have 23, 24 or 25 hours, because of daylight saving times