# Creating an NSDate which is "Tomorrow at 7:00AM"

Tags: ios4

How can I create an NSDate which is set to tomorrow at 7:00AM?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help you:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html

See also: [How do i add 1 day to a NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-a-nsdate)