# How to get particular time with my current date?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i add 1 day to a NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-a-nsdate)

I wan't to add time(10.00 AM) in `NSDate`

In `string` I get the data like this:

```
10:00 AM
```

I want to convert this time `string` to `NSDate` with current date.

In `NSDate` I wan't data like `2013-01-24 10:00:00 +0000`

I want this data in `NSDate`.

Please suggest me how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"10:00 AM"];
```