# Get specific date - Objective c iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, date

I want to get the date that will be in 45 days from today in objective C - iphone.
I'm new in objective C :)

I know that i can do somthing like:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Tue, 16 April 2013 13:00:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, d LLLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr]; 
[dateFormat release];
```

But, i do not want a static allocate... it should be dynamic. 
Every day i need to get in `*date` variable the date of 45 days from today.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-a-nsdate

Comment: What is static and what you say dynamic? `[NSDate date]` is always dynamic returns the current date.

Comment: @George: That is not a good solution, that is accepted there. It doesn't care about daylight, leap seconds etc

Comment: I mean, i need the date that will be 45 days from today, Every day! not the date of 45 days from today date

Comment: @lolo: yes every day your date will be +45 from that day, because [NSDate date] will return that day's date and you are adding 45 days to it.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way:

```
NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.day=45;
NSDate *targetDate =[calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:today options: 0];
```