# Find the NSDate for next Monday

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdate, date-arithmetic

I want to get the date of the next Monday after the current date.

So if today's date is 2013-08-09 (Friday) then I want to get the date 2013-08-12.

How can I do this?

Comment: Although this is a simple question and requires little effort, dates are annoying as hell in any language so i don't see why you should be down-voted.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This piece of code should get what you want. It simply calculates how many days are from monday and append it from current's date.

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];

NSUInteger weekdayToday = [components weekday];  
NSInteger daysToMonday = (9 - weekdayToday) % 7;

NSDate *nextMonday = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToMonday];
```

Untested, but should work, and **without** worrying about changing first dates of calendar.

**And** it can even be easily addapted to **every another day** of the week, just change the `9`inside `(9 - weekdayToday) % 7;` by `7 + weekDayYouWant`, remembering that sunday = 1, monday = 2...

Comment: Thanks Lucas , works perfectly. Just one thing , if today is Monday then I want to show next Monday instead of this Monday. Can you tell me how can I achieve this ? Thanks again

Comment: I don't think there's a elegant way to change the behaviour for just one day like that. But you can **add** (not replace) something like that, **before** the ```nextMonday``` code: ```daysToMonday = (daysToMonday == 0) ? 7 : daysToMonday;``` . In this way, you would be adding 7 days instead of 0 days when the current day is monday. If you find a better solution for this case, just let me know

Comment: won't work for daylight savings time. See this for modified solution for adding the days http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-a-nsdate

Comment: Since macOS 10.9 / iOS 8 the recommended way is `nextDayAfterDate:matchingComponents:options:` of `NSCalendar`. It can consider daylight saving changes all over the world and is much more reliable than `86400`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NSCalendar` method `dateFromComponents:` passing a properly initiated `NSDateComponents` object

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setWeekOfYear:[components weekOfYear] + 1];
[comps setWeekday:1];
[comps setYear:[components year]];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[calendar setFirstWeekday:2]; //This needs to be checked, which day is monday?
NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Something along these lines could work (blindly typed)

Comment: assuming the week begins in sunday (week day = 0), wouldn't this code get the monday of the week after instead of only the day after when running on sundays?

Comment: Weekday units are the numbers 1 through n, where n is the number of days in the week. For example, in the Gregorian calendar, n is 7 and Sunday is represented by 1.

So yes, probably the code needs to be changed

Comment: I slightly edited the code to take this into account. Of course one should also check that the current day isn't the last week of the year and so on..

Comment: @Vik its not work, but i like that approach.