# Fire UILocalNotification according to day with hours and minutes in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have to fire `UILocalNotification` according to particular day with `hours` and `minutes` but don't have `date`. E.g. I have to fire `UILocalNotification` on every "`Mon 02:30 PM`". How can I set local notification like this?

Please suggest me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the UILocalNotification's `repeatInterval` to `NSCalendarUnitWeekday`

```
  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
      UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert categories:nil];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  }  else {
      UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
  }

  UILocalNotification *notification=[[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

  NSDate *currentDate   = [NSDate date];

  notification.fireDate = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:10.0];

  notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekday;

  notification.alertBody   = @"Wake up, man";
  notification.soundName= UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

  notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber++;

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Comment: How can I pass just Mon 02:30 PM as fire date in UIlocalNotification

Answer (score 1):

Get the next monday date from current date.For that follow this Link [Next Monday Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148224/get-next-monday-date-in-ios)

After that set `notification` for it and set the `repeat interval` to `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear` so the notification will trigger every monday.

Answer (score 0):

You get the system date and time, and use that to set your logic.

In pseudocode:

```
if today == monday {

    if time == 2:30 PM {

        fire local notification .
    }
}
```

Comment: But  I have to set multiple localnotifications. This can be future time also

Comment: use UILocalNotification's repeatInterval to NSCalendarUnitWeekday

Comment: How can I pass just Mon 02:30 PM as fire date in UIlocalNotification