# How to store NSDate in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

When generating Core Data subclasses I check to use primitive data type in Core Data storage.

[image]

Which `NSTimeInterval` representation should I convert from `NSDate`? Or it does not matter, just use appropriately when reading / writing the same managed object attribute?

I prefere to use like: `mo.creationDate = date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS's reference date counts from : 1 January 2001, GMT.
Unix Time Stamp reference date counts from : Jan 01 1970, UTC

If this is a completely offline app you can use the timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate and store the value directly.

But, if you are going to sync up with a server then generally, it is preferable to send the data to server as a unix time stamp. Because a desktop uses unix time Stamp as default.

So, in the second case you can either choose to save the date directly as a UnixTimeStamp and convert it for local use using a getter in Model Class (refer : @VladZ) or You can save it as iOS's reference date and convert it to UnixTimeStamp each time you send it to server.

Answer (score 1):

Use - timeIntervalSince1970 and save this value in CoreDate

```
mo.creationDate = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:timeInterval];
```

Comment: why not `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`?

Comment: it doesn't matter. You may use timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a time interval, that it's not an object of type NSDate.

Try to add a NSDate with the desired time interval:

[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-a-nsdate)