# ios: Get 3 weeks (by date) ahead

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate, nscalendar

I need to get 3 weeks with dates ahead from current date. and add all dates to an array.
How I can get this?

```
 let date = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
        let comps = calendar?.components([.Day, .WeekOfMonth, .Month], fromDate: date)
        let days = calendar?.rangeOfUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Day, inUnit: NSCalendarUnit.Month, forDate: date)
        print(days?.length)
```

This code gives me days in current month. But 3 weaks ahead could take next month

> for example today is 16.02 I need print something like this
>
> 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 01 02 04....

thanks for advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-a-nsdate

Comment: This solution not including daylight saving time

Comment: func dateByAddingComponents(_ comps: NSDateComponents, toDate date: NSDate, options opts: NSCalendarOptions) -> NSDate?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shows no research effort. read the docs plz :)

Comment: Daij-Djan What about my answer?Is it good answer to question?

Answer (score 1):

how about this, which generates an array of the days as requested

```
    var date = NSDate()
    var days : [String] = []

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"

    for _ in 0...20
    {
        days.append(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))

        // move on to the next day
        date = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
            .Day,
            value: 1,
            toDate: date,
            options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!
    }
    print(days)
```

Comment: Yes, I wrote the same :) see my updated answer :) but thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found some solution. As I know in each week 7 days * 3 = 21

```
   // MARK: - Next 3 weeks
    func nextThreeWeeks() -> Array<String> {
        let date = NSDate()
        var days : Array<String> = []
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
        let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)

        for i in 0 ..< 21 {
            let next21Days = calendar!.dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Day, value: i, toDate: date, options: [])
            days.append(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(next21Days!))
        }
        return days
    }
```

It will print following dates:

> Optional(2016-02-16 12:03:41 +0000)
>   Optional(2016-02-17 12:03:41 +0000)
>   Optional(2016-02-18 12:03:41 +0000)
>   Optional(2016-02-19 12:03:41 +0000)
>   ...
>   Optional(2016-03-06 12:03:41 +0000)
>   Optional(2016-03-07 12:03:41 +0000)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution with printed result what you ask exactly.

Below the code and output

```
  var arrayDate = [String]()

  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for var intWeek = 0; intWeek < 21; ++intWeek
    {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd"
        let dateComponents: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
        dateComponents.day = intWeek
        let date = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: date, options:NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))
        let startOfDay = formatter.stringFromDate(components!)
        arrayDate.append(startOfDay)
        print("The dates are - \(arrayDate)")
    }
  }
```

Output Results

```
The dates are - ["16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07"]
```

Thank you so much Anton

Comment: Thank you, already posted own answer. It will help to someone else

Comment: My answer is different from both of your answer.