# Adding days/hours to NSDate with Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate

I know it is a really basic question, and I am aware I might not be finding the answer because I am not asking the right question however how can I change the NSDate value ?

For Example I have a `date` property which is set to the date of a `datePicker` and I want to create a new property which is the day before the `date` property and another which is an hour before.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Adding and removing days

In order to avoid problems with daylight summer time, when you are adding days you should use `NSCalendar`

Swift 3 :

```
let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding:
    .day, // updated this params to add hours
    value: 1,
    to: now)
```

Swift 2 :

```
let tomorrow = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
    .Day, // updated this params to add hours
    value: 1,
    toDate: now,
    options: .MatchFirst)
```

> Please note that you are **NOT** mutating the original instance (`now`), you are simply building a new one. Infact the `NSDate` class is **immutable**.

Comment: Using `7 * 24 * 60 * 60` as the duration of a day is wrong. In regions with daylight summer time, a day may have 23 or 25 hours. The correct way is to use NSCalendar, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27048988/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR: Thank you. I updated my answer.