# Swift add 1 week to current date

Tags: swift, datepicker

I am using a `datePicker` and trying to establish the minimum date as the current date and the maximum being a week from today. I cannot seem to get the max working. Here is my code:

```
calendarView.minimumDate = todaysDate
calendarView.maximumDate = [todaysDate .dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60*24*10)]
```

Comment: Refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-a-nsdate

Comment: 1) Never do date math using `dateByAddingTimeInterval`. 2) Why are you trying to add 10 days when you want to add 1 week?

Comment: What is todaysDate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add 1 day to an NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-an-nsdate)

Answer (score 21):

You can do:

```
let today = NSDate()
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)
let nextWeek = cal!.dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendar.Unit.Day, value: 7, toDate: today, options: NSCalendar.Options.MatchLast)
```

This will print out `2016-09-14 04:21:14`

### Swift 5.x

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let addOneWeekToCurrentDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: 1, to: Date())
```

Comment: Never use the first option. It will be wrong in some cases.

Comment: I was looking for a ".week" property, but I guess this works too!

Comment: I was concerned if using a different calendar, but apparently almost all calendars have 7 days in a week: https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/why-cant-we-get-rid-of-the-7day-week

Answer (score 7):

This code works well even if over the year-end.

```swift
Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: 1, to: date)
```

Comment: Is there any difference in using `.weekOfMonth` instead of `.weekOfYear` in this case? I tried different calendars, locales and timezones but it seems to work fine

Answer (score 2):

```
    extension Date {
    func addWeek(noOfWeeks: Int) -> Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: noOfWeeks, to: self)!
    }
   }
    //USAGE    
    let newDate = Date().addWeek(noOfWeeks: 3)
```