# In Swift, how to delete hours in a Date object?

Tags: swift, date, formatter

i need to use a dictionary of dates, and i need to delete all the information about a date except:
day
month
year

i create this static function:

```
let day = Date() // it's an example
print(day)

func dateSimplificator(WithDate date: Date) -> Date {
    let formatterD = DateFormatter()
    formatterD.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy"
    let dayString = formatterD.string(from: date)
    let reFormatterD = DateFormatter()
    reFormatterD.dateFormat = "dd MM yyyy"
    let dayFormatted = reFormatterD.date(from: dayString)!
    //print(dayFormatted)
    return dayFormatted
}

print(dateSimplificator(WithDate: day))
```

and when i print, i obtain:
2020-09-03 10:40:25 +0000
2020-09-02 23:00:00 +0000

it isn't what i want.
I need somthing like this:

the date => 2020-09-03 10:40:25 +0000
and when i use the static function with the date, i have to obtain a new date like this :
2020-09-02 00:00:00 +0000

what should a change in my function?

Comment: The best solution is to always use the same time for instance by doing `let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: day)`

Comment: but it creates a time with not 00 in the hours ! and a need that the date has eveything at zero except day month and year

Comment: That's because of the time zone, the important part is that all dates get the same time.

Comment: @Wahib for a time insensitive date you should use noon instead of midnight. Not all dates starts at 12am https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009804/swift-3-how-to-get-date-for-tomorrow-and-yesterday-take-care-special-case-ne/44009988#44009988

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your method can be written without a date formatter

```
func dateSimplificator(with date: Date) -> Date {
    return Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: date)
}
```

Second of all a date formatter considers the local time zone – which is clearly UTC+0100 in your case – but `print` shows dates in UTC. `2020-09-03 00:00:00 +0100` and `2020-09-02 23:00:00 +0000` is the same moment in time.

Comment: i agree with you about the same moment in time. But my function needs to use other dates than only today, so i can't use your proposition

Comment: `startOfDay(for:` returns the correct value for any date, even for a locale where the daylight saving time changes at midnight.