# Calculate if a date is the day after another date using Swift

Tags: swift, date

I know how to use Date components and check how many days, hours, years etc. have passed between 2 dates.

However, what I want to know is whether the new date is the next day from a pervious day.

For example the last day could be March 12 2022 11:59PM
And the new day could be March 13 2022 12:01 AM that would count as the next day.

Calculating the difference between the two dates would result in 2 min but that's not what I want. I want to check whether it's the next day.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is calendar method `isInSameDay` as date. So first you get your second date and get its day after as shown here [How to get date for tomorrow and yesterday (take care special case) new month or new year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44009988/2303865), then you just need to check if it is in same day as the first date Something like:

```
extension Date {
    var dayBefore: Date {
        Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: noon)!
    }
    var dayAfter: Date {
        Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: noon)!
    }
    var noon: Date {
        Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)!
    }
    func isInSameDay(as date: Date) -> Bool {
        Calendar.current.isDate(self, inSameDayAs: date)
    }
    func isDayBefore(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
        isInSameDay(as: date.dayBefore)
    }
    func isDayAfter(_ date: Date) -> Bool {
        isInSameDay(as: date.dayAfter)
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let cal = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
let date1 = DateComponents(calendar: cal, year: 2022, month: 3, day: 12, hour: 23, minute: 59).date!
let date2 = DateComponents(calendar: cal, year: 2022, month: 3, day: 13, hour: 0, minute: 1).date!

date1.isDayBefore(date2)  // true
date2.isDayAfter(date1)   // true

date1.isDayAfter(date2)   // false
date2.isDayBefore(date1)  // false
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution for this kind of problem is to calculate the difference while ignoring time. The simplest method to do that is to start using `DateComponents` instead of `Date`.

Let's create some testing data first:

```
let parser = ISO8601DateFormatter()
parser.formatOptions = .withInternetDateTime

let date1 = parser.date(from: "2022-03-12T23:59:00Z")!
let date2 = parser.date(from: "2022-03-13T00:01:00Z")!
```

Let's show the problem:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
// make sure to set time zone correctly to correspond with the test data above
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!

let componentDiff = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
print(componentDiff.day!) // 0
```

Now let's see the solution:

```
// take only the day components, ignoring the time
let components1 = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date1)
let components2 = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date2)

// calculate the difference only between the day components
let componentDiff2 = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: components1, to: components2)
print(componentDiff2.day!) // 1
```