# Date formating, adding days to date

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

Here is my first question;

```
import Foundation 

let date1 = Date()
let date2 = Date().addingTimeInterval(3600)

if date1 == date2
{
          print("equals")
}
else if date1 > date2
{
          print("date1 is bigger")
}
else if date1 < date2
{
          print("date2 is bigger")
}
```

It gives below output if i write print("date1") or print("date2")

> 2018-09-10 08:56:49 +0000

I would like to write the same example but `date1` and `date2` must include these 2 properties:

format: `"dd.MM.yyyy"`

locale: `"tr_TR"`

Beside this, here is my second question:

```
let date2 = Date().addingTimeInterval(3600)
```

As you know, this 3600 value adding an hour. How can I add one day? 24*3600? Is there any shortest way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5067868/1891327

Comment: Note that `24*3600` is not always a full day. There're sometimes summer time/winter time, and next day at the same hour could be 23 or 25 hours from current time. Look for `Calendar` to add a day."I would like to write the same example but date1 and date2 must include these 2 properties:" Look for `DateFormatter`.

Comment: Thanks for these details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i add 1 day to a NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-a-nsdate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Larme said, you might want to look into [`Calendar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar).

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.day = 1
guard let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: Date()) else {  // Adding date components to current day.
   fatalError("date not found")
}
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short // dd.MM.yyyy
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "tr_TR") // Your preferred locale
let dateWithLocale = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
print(date)
```

Your comparison can be done using the `Date` objects. Only when you need to print it or use it as a `String`, you would need to do formatting.

Comment: Dear, @Rakesha Shastri, I have question: Let's assume, i have this variable:     var birthday : Date? = nil    Can I set a current date value to the this birtday variable. But in short format. (Not as a string. You know, birthday is in Date type) Thanks.

Comment: @mannyCalavera An instance of `Date` does not have a format. Only when it is converted to string, formatting is relevant. Whenever you use dates for display, you always convert them to a string before using it. This is when you do the formatting part with DateFormatter. For comparison, you can use the date objects. For example, let's say you have 2 integers, a and b (1 & 2). During comparison it doesn't matter if it is stored as `Double`, `Float` or `Int` as long as the value isn't changed. But when you display it, you will convert it to a particular format. eg: 1.00 using string formatting.

Comment: Understand. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When can we see that fatalError("date not found")? I mean, is there any possibility to see this fatalError scope? It gets the current date and then it adds one day. Which case we see this fatalError scope. I just wonder Dear @Rakesha Shastri

Comment: Like link below?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-a-nsdate

Comment: @mannyCalavera Hmm... good question. I can't think of one immediately, i just wrapped it up in a guard statement because the date returned by `Calendar` was optional.

Comment: @mannyCalavera i just tried subtracting 100000000 from the current date and it still returned a "\n" as a value for date. So i guess it is something like `UITextField`'s text property.

Comment: Thanks @Rakesha Shastri

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
extension Date {
  func addDays(_ days: Int) -> Date {
    Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.date(byAdding: .day, value: days, to: self)!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
let today = Date() // OR your date here
let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: today)
let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: today)
```