# Is there an equivalent to Java's TimeUnit class in Objective-C and Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm creating a method that is reliant on a certain amount of time having elapsed. It has to be readable by a non-technical person, so the time has to be in days

```
let daysBetweenRequests = 130
```

But for that to work with an TimeInterval comparison, it needs to be in milliseconds. In Objective-C or Swift, is there an equivalent to Java's TimeUnit class that will perform the conversion of days to milliseconds for me, or do I need to roll the conversion myself? Something like:

```
let daysAsMilliseconds = TimeConverter.convert(from: daysBetweenRequests, to: .milliseconds)
```

I'm fine doing it, but it seems like there would be a built-in, and I can't seem to find one. Thanks!

Comment: `NSDateComponentsFormatter`? There is also this `NSCalendar` method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1409577-datebyaddingcomponents?language=objc ?

Comment: Cool, thanks! If you provide an example as an answer, I'd be happy to upvote and select it as the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-an-nsdate ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add 1 day to an NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-an-nsdate)