# Add next week (7 days) from current var (Int) to 10 digit unix timestamp in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift

To allow users change their username one time per week i want to add limit.
So i have loginUpdateDate var and it returns 10 digit timestamp (Int) and it's ok.
How can i add 7 days to this variable?
Not from the beginning of the week, namely from the moment of rewriting this variable.
I'm trying lastLoginUpdate * 24 * 60 * 60 but seems it wrong (I'm studying).
So i need to this Int variable (10 digit) add 7 days.
And then from tis variable subtract one day every day (To show user how many days remaining to next login change availability)

Comment: Don't multiply your last login date by your time offset. Add it instead. `lastLoginUpdate += 7 * 24 * 60 * 60`. From there, you could just get the current date and compare the two rather than trying to subtract one every day.

Comment: @David maybe you abble to help me please i'm trying to add check for current time in var with next week but it's not working, something like this let currentDate = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970) if loginUpdateDate < currentDate += 7 * 24 * 60 * 60, i have "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the accuracy you want either add 7 * 24 * 60 to your timestamp as suggested in the comments is one way.

Note you could also create a date from the timestamp and use the appropriate date functions as described here: [How do I add 1 day to an NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067785/how-do-i-add-1-day-to-an-nsdate)

if your loginUpdateDate is a Swift Date, just use the code in the link. Otherwise use the timestamp (the 10 digit int) to create a date:

```
let lastLoginDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: lastLoginUpdate)
var dayComponent    = DateComponents()
dayComponent.day    = 1 // For removing one day (yesterday): -1
let theCalendar     = Calendar.current
let nextAllowedDate        = theCalendar.date(byAdding: dayComponent, to: lastLoginDate)
```

Comment: Not every day has 24 hours. Therefore 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 might give you unexpected results. You should always use the calendar method with the desired timezone.

Comment: Please post a new question and not to the comment. And also take a look at NSDate / Date methods for getting time differences.