# How to convert NSString in to NSDate format

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

How to convert this NSString(Tue, 13 Mar 2012 00:00:00 -0500) into NSDate format

Comment: You need to refer to http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/

Comment: You also need to refer to: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html

Answer (score 1):

NSDateFormatter uses the [Unicode Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns).

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate ];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"eee, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init] ;
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: Line 1 leaks (no release or autorelease), line 3 "double leaks" (alloc & retain, no release or autorelease).