# Calculate next date in week

Tags: ios, nsdate

I am building a tutorial schedule application and I need to be able to calculate the next date. Specifically, I need to calculate either the next Saturday or Tuesday in the week (depending which one comes first) based on the current date.

Today is Monday, July 15, 2013. The next Tuesday is on July 16, 2013. The next Saturday is July 20, 2013. Therefore I would need the date Tuesday, July 16, 2013.

Can anyone please tell me how I could figure this out?

Thank you!

Comment: any code you have tried?

Comment: Google NSDateComponents.

Comment: -1 For not providing details.  This is not an uncommon or difficult problem which suggests a lack of research.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` to get NSDateComponents from the current date, especially `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` and `NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit`. the components will have a member `weekday`, that ranges from `1 — sunday` to `7 — saturday`. if it is `1` or `2`, create a new componets with weekday `2`, if it is `7`, add one to `weekOfYear` and set weekday to `2`. for all other cases set `weekday` to `7`.

Now use `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` again to create a day from the components.