# How to convert string date to NSDate

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdateformatter

I need to convert 2013/5/23 to day. here the problem is month is having as 5.

`2013/5/23 => Thursday`

code that I am using:

```
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];
        
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2013/5/23"];
        NSLog(@"Date :%@",date);
        
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
        NSLog(@"DAY %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

and the output is

> Date :2013-05-22 18:30:00 +0000
>
> DAY Thursday

Actually day is printed correctly according to my input date. But printed date is wrong.
it should be `2013-05-23`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

Comment: read Apple's documentation for NSDateFormatter and look up examples of its usage.

Comment: i have check that answer. but my problem is month is having as 5. not 05.

Comment: Your month is being parsed correctly; the issue is with formatting the date back to a day using `EEEE`.  I believe your code should work. Please clarify what you mean by "but when i print the date it's giving as"; is that the final `NSLog()` statement?

Comment: "when i print the date it's giving as" ?? please describe you this line?

Comment: Agree with @Rajneesh071 what do you want exactly? Please clear. What is the problem if you print date ?

Comment: He want's `2013/5/23` converted to `Thursday`.

Comment: i have update the question. i want to convert 2013/5/23 to Thursday. but when i print the date it's giving as 2013-05-22 18:30:00 +0000

Comment: @Rocky Once again then: **WHAT DO YOU MEAN BY "WHEN I PRINT THE DATE"???  IS THAT THE FINAL NSLOG() STATEMENT OR ARE YOU PRINTING THE NSDATE OBJECT**.

Comment: check now buddy.. it will print your date...

Comment: when im printing the nsdate obj it's giving the wrong date

Comment: @Rocky and what would you expect the `NSDate` object to contain?

Comment: @trojanfoe While I applaud your attempts to get to the bottom of this; the date is actually correct, except that the user hasn't accounted for the timezone. Local midnight for him is 6:30pm GMT, which is what the log is showing.

Comment: @Abizern I think the OP is confused that calling `[NSDate description]` (by way of `NSLog(@"%@");`) is **not** the same as using `NSDateFormatter` to get the date in the format he wants.  He doesn't mention anything about timezones in his question and says that all he wants is the day-of-week for the specified input date.  I think the question is completely bogus.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

Comment: can any one explain reason of down voting? i want to improve answer if  you have proper solution, and if don't have then no need to down vote..

Answer (score 0):

you can set timezone like

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
```