# Convert NSString in hh:mm:ss format to NSDate for Timer Countdown

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have to run a countdown timer  for a specific interval but how to feed self.startDate in this function

```
- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    // has the target time passed?
    if ([self.startDate earlierDate:now] == self.startDate) {
        [theTimer invalidate];
    } else {
        NSUInteger flags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:now toDate:self.startDate options:0];

        NSLog(@"there are %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds remaining", [components hour], [components minute], [components second]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to setStartDate from which time/string?

Comment: -1 This is very basic NSDateFormatter stuff.  If you had tried *at all* to look it up you would have found your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert NSString to NSDate using:

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
  NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourString];
```