# Parse NSString to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have dates inside strings with this format:

```
2014-02-05T23:09:19.642Z
2014-02-05T23:09:54.645Z
...
```

I've tried to parse them to NSDate doing the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

But date is ending up being null, so how this needs to be done?

I tried with:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ"];
```

And it works for

```
2014-02-05T23:13:51.000Z
```

But not with:

```
2014-02-05T23:23:44.420Z
2014-02-05T23:01:19.620Z
...
```

Comment: You're missing the fractional seconds in your format.

Comment: I don't think this deserves a down-vote

Comment: do you mean like this: [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ"]; ? I tried this and it didn't work

Comment: @Madbreaks Yes it does. There are countless existing questions on this topic and a simple scan of the date format specification would answer it quickly.

Comment: Maybe you should actually consult [the documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can easily be answered by consulting the available documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your formatter to

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sss.SSSZ"];
```

Since in your time string `2014-02-05T23:09:19.642Z` you have milliseconds there, so you need to add SSS for those milliseconds