# Format a string to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to convert a string to NSDate but I'm getting an error.

```
NSLog(@"JSON %@", responseObject);
NSArray *login = responseObject;
NSString *expires = [login valueForKey:@"expires"];
NSLog(@"%@", expires);
```

NSLog of responseObject (I used MMRecord 1.3 and AFNetworking 2)

```
<Login: 0x91dcdb0> (entity: Login; id: 0x91dcdf0 <x-coredata:///Login/t82A1AC69-501C-4C49-BAEE-C676FD655FDE2> ; data: {\n    \"access_token\" = \"******************\";\n    error = nil;\n    \"error_description\" = nil;\n    expires = \"Thu, 22 May 2014 02:30:21 GMT\";\n    \"expires_in\" = 1209599;\n    \"grant_type\" = nil;\n    issued = \"Thu, 08 May 2014 02:30:21 GMT\";\n    password = nil;\n    \"token_type\" = ***;\n    userName = \"su@email.in\";\n    userid = nil;\n})
```

When I NSLog that string `expires` I get something like this

```
(
"Thu, 22 May 2014 02:17:02 GMT"
)
```

If I do anything operation on that string, I'm getting this error

```
[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9754950
```

I think, for some reason, `expires` is of type NSArray. Can You tell me what wrong with this? How can I change it to NSDate? I'm new to iOS. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: That's because `expires` is another `NSArray`, not an `NSString`. Show the log output from the 1st `NSLog` in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy updated my question for first NSLog

Comment: That's not an NSArray.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
NSString *expires = [[login valueForKey:@"expires"] firstObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the key @"expires" refers to an array, not a string.  If you can be sure that it's always an array and will always be non-empty, then you can fix with:

```
NSArray *expiresArray = login[@"expires"];
NSString *expires = expiresArray[0];
```

The next thing you'll want is an NSDate.  See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again) for that.