# Convert string into date in ios

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have my data in JSON format which contains some date:

```
"NOME_PUBBL_LINEA" = "FOLLONICA - PIOMBINO";
    "ORA_ARRIVA" = "1899-12-30T06:45:00";
    "ORA_PARTE" = "1899-12-30T05:50:00";
```

I want to convert it like :

```
 ora_arriva = 6.45,
   ora_parte = 5.50
```

I have tried following :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+02:00'"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Italy/Rome"]];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:dataDic[@"ORA_ARRIVA"]];
```

But it is giving me like

> 1899-12-30 00:51:40 +0000

for ora_arriva.

Comment: It's probably the classic `YYYY` should be `yyyy`...

Comment: Once you got the `NSDate dte`, change the format as you want, and convert to `NSString`.

Comment: @trojanfoe both are giving me same output

Comment: What about the "+02:00" bit.  That is wrong for sure.

Comment: Also you need to know the time zone of the JSON date and set it in the date formatter object.

Comment: It's crucial to know it (it's probably/hopefully GMT/UTC).

Comment: @trojanfoe I just want time in output...If I only fetch time from date string then...is it proper way to acheive output as I want only time

Comment: You have to parse the date correctly first.  Then you can use the answer from @Zhang to extract the time elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56184/discussion-between-vivek-and-trojanfoe).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

Answer (score 0):

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+02:00'"];
```

Just yyyy :)

Comment: That format doesn't appear to match that required by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

dateFromString returns an NSDate. You need take that NSDate object and construct your time:

```
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorianCalendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:myDate];

NSLog(@"current time = %ld:%ld", [comp hour], [comp minute]);
```

Replace the `myDate` with your actual NSDate you got back from your `dateFormatter`

Comment: The issue is that the time is wrong, not that the OP is unable to extract hour/minute from the parsed date.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateformatter stringFromDate:adate];
```