# Date conversion from string to NSDate in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have searched over internet for a long time to get this but I can't find the solution. I have  received a date string from web services as `"22 May 2014"`, I have to convert into `NSDate` format for check it with current date. And I have to find out the date from web service is in future or in past time.

The actual problem is that when I convert this using

```
NSDate *date;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM YYYY"];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

But I get an entirely Different Date, Sample Input dateString:`22 June 2014` and Output I get  is `2013-12-21 18:30:00+0000`

Please suggest any solutions.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You are right @Jon Skeet..@Sudheesh Plz refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `YYYY`, which doesn't mean what you think it means. From the [TR35-31](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) documentation, `Y` is the symbol for "year in week-of-year calendars".

You want `dd MMMM yyyy` instead as your format string. Mixing week-of-year-based fields and regular day/month/year fields is a recipe for odd problems.

Additionally, you may well want to set the time zone in your formatter - if you're just parsing a date, then you should consider using UTC, and make sure that *all* your calculations and formatting/parsing use UTC.

(I suspect the issue here is that week-of-year hasn't been set, so is assumed to be 1... and the week-year 2014 started on December 30th. Then the day-of-month is set to 22 by the dd part, and then your time zone offset of UTC+05:30 is taken into account.)

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet for the sudden reply, I've checked it and found working.

Comment: Dammit Jon, you're everywhere, even on iOS tagged question. Is there some tag I can't find you on ? :)