# Get Date from String Containing Timestamp

Tags: string, date, swift, timestamp

How can a date be extracted from a string containing a timestamp using Swift?

***For example:***

When given the following timeStamp in string format, what steps are necessary to extract the date and convert it to a string?

if the timeStamp = `"3/5/2015 7:12:17 PM"`

then desired result would be = `"3/5/2015"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27369380/2303865

Comment: There are several thousand questions exactly like this on stack overflow already. By asking another one you're saying that none of those were able to help you in any way whatsoever?

Comment: @Fogmeister The selected answer was able to provide additional insight into manipulating the timestamp that I was unable to harvest via existing Q&A's on Stack Overflow. Additionally, much of the existing information is in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let input = "3/5/2015 7:12:17 PM"
let output = "3/5/2015"

extension NSDate {
    var formatted: String {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy"
        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
extension String {
    var asNSDate:NSDate {
        let styler = NSDateFormatter()
        styler.dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a"
        return styler.dateFromString(self) ?? NSDate()
    }
}

println( input.asNSDate.formatted ) // "3/5/2015"
```