# How to format NSDateFormatter for this date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

How would I format a `NSDateFormatter` to create a date from the following format?

`Sat May 16 13:45:36 2015`

The part of `Sat May 16` is the part that I am unsure how to do

I know the last part would be `HH:mm:ss yyyy`

Comment: Have you checked [the spec](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)?

Comment: This is a good reference: http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateString = "Sat May 16 13:45:36 2015"
let df = NSDateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy"
df.dateFromString(dateString)   // "May 16, 2015, 1:45 PM"
```

You should take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27369380/2303865) also.