# How to convert the NSString of format (2015-04-30T21:53:11.0000) to NSDate? in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Could you please let me know How to convert the NSString of format (2015-04-30T21:53:11.0000) to NSDate? in Swift.

Comment: Read the documentation, perhaps?

Comment: Whats does the capital T in the middle stand for?  Is it Tuesday or Thursday?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again

Comment: Here is Answer.
  func dateFromString(string: String) -> NSDate? {
    let df = NSDateFormatter()
    df.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS'Z'"
    var date: NSDate? = df.dateFromString(string)
    
    if date == nil {
      df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
      date = df.dateFromString(string)
    }
    
    return date
  }

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`dateFromString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/dateFromString:) method in iOS' [date formatter class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html).

There are a zillion examples and explanations just a google search away.  Most will be in Objective-C, but that's very easy to convert to Swift.

Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

You would use NSDateFormatter for this.

```
let orig = "2015-04-30T21:53:11.0000"

let dsFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dsFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS"
let dsDate = dsFormatter.dateFromString(orig)
```