# Convert NSSting to NSDate

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring, nsdate

I have string 2015-08-10T12:00 how can I convert it to Date?

My code did not works

```
      [self.dataFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm"];
            NSDate *date = [self.dataFormatter dateFromString:dateStg];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this date format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm
```

Comment: `@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm"` -> you have to mark the `T` as an actual character and not as part of the "format".

Answer (score -1):

## converted current Date into String

```
//Get Current Date
    NSLocale *en_US_POSIX = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    assert(en_US_POSIX != nil);
    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:en_US_POSIX];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
```

## Converted Current Time inTo NSString

```
 //Get Current Date
    NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSCalendarUnitHour  | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:now];
    NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
    NSString *am_OR_pm=@"AM";
    if (hour>12){
        hour=hour%12;
        am_OR_pm = @"PM";
    }
    NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
    NSString *strTime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d %@", hour, minute ,am_OR_pm];
```

## Converted NSString to NSDate

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
// voila!
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```