# Failed in convert NSString from kABBirthdayProperty to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried to convert NSString to NSDate as the instruction: [NSString to NSdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

My snippet does not work, maybe the source NSString extracts incorrect
 from ABPerson, with kABBirthdayProperty. It gets error with reason:

```
-[__NSTaggedDate bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc1c3a7619800000d
```

This is the snippet:

```
-(void) abRead: (ABPerson*) myRecord
   {  if ([myRecord valueForProperty:kABBirthdayProperty] != nil)
        { NSDateFormatter* myBirthday = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
          [myBirthday setDateFormat:@"YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS"];
          NSDate* birthDay = [myBirthday dateFromString:[myRecord valueForProperty:kABBirthdayProperty]];
   }
```

I guess that the NSString got from kABBirthdayProperty have some special format or some thing. I checked:

```
NSLog(@"birthday: %@", [myRecord valueForProperty:kABBirthdayProperty]);
```

it print out as NSString should be:

```
birthday :1980-02-08 05:00:00 +0000
```

Do I need any conversion from ABPerson:kABProperty to NSString correctly?

sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

That property is already an `NSDate*`, it is not an `NSString*`.  As such, you should not try and convert it from an `NSString*` to an `NSDate*` and just use it as an `NSDate*` directly:

```
-(void) abRead: (ABPerson*) myRecord {
    NSDate* birthDay = [myRecord valueForProperty:kABBirthdayProperty];
    if (birthday != nil) {
        // Do something with birthday
    }
}
```

The error you are getting actually tells you this:

> -[__NSTaggedDate bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc1c3a7619800000d

This is telling you that an instance of type `__NSTaggedDate` is having the method `bytes` called on it.  This implies that you're treating a type as if it is a different type.

Comment: @ML1426 You may want to mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem, so people with a similar issue will know.

Comment: I newbie and wait till enough reputation for mark this. do it later when ready.