# Convert NSString to NSDate is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i use code same this best answer

[Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
// voila!
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

but dateFromString result is 2010-01-31 17:00:00 +0000
why it not same day.
i cannot compare date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of your current time zone, add this then it will give u correct date

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line right after where you have set the date format. It because it will convert by default with local timezone of the device. It works for me!

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually the same date. But the date formatter, by default, parses the date string in the local timezone of the device if a timezone is not passed in. In your case, your date was intepreted as Midnight February 2nd 2010 UTC+7 which is January 31st 2010 17:00 UTC.

If the date string is always in UTC, pass in the UTC timezone into the date formatter like this:

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
// voila!
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```