# Swift 2: Parse RSS pubDate to NSDate object

Tags: swift2, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I´m trying to **convert a String (Date)** from an RSS Feed ("pubDate") to an **NSDate object** in Swift 2.

```
let dateString:String = "Tue, 16 Aug 2016 15:27:33 +0000"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
print(date)
```

The problem is, that **in that case the date object is always nil**. The problem is the **format of the input string**. If I **change dateString to "2016-08-16"** then the **NSDate object is built correctly**.

So I´ve no idea how to get this NSDate working. String operations on the dateString before? Or some options on the dateFormatter?

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: Your date format matches `2016-08-16`. You need the proper date format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

Comment: Adapt your dateFormat to your dateString by following this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lkYVY.png

Answer (score 7):

While questions about how to convert from string to date is mostly about specifying the right format string, you should read what Apple has to say about [NSDateFormatter and Internet Dates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1480/_index.html). The short version is that you should always specify the local as `en_US_POSIX`:

```
let dateString = "Tue, 16 Aug 2016 15:27:33 +0000"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
print(date)
```