# How to convert from one date format to another Swift 3

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I have a String is this format:

> 2017-10-09 13:28:36 +0000
>   "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"

I would like to present dates like so:

> Mon Oct 9th
>   "EEEE, MMM d, h:mm a"

Should I just Calendar Components to construct the date or is there a way to use DateFormatter?

I currently download JSON that contains User "Checkins" and the time they checkedin:

```
if let dateTime = dict["dateTime"] as? String {
   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
   dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
   let myDate =  dateFormatter.date(from: dateTime)!
   print(myDate) // 2017-10-09 13:28:36 +0000
   // dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d, h:mm a" Desired Date Format

   checkinObject.dateTime = myDate
```

}

Comment: `DateFormatter` does not support ordinal days like 9th. By the way: The input format does not match the string at all. The matching format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z`

Comment: check answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again