# i need to convert time to date format

Tags: ios, objective-c

time is string format like 10:27:43. but when i convert in to date format. it is  going to change Sat Jan  1 10:27:43 2000.but i need only time like 10:27:43

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"];

 NSLog(@"Date is %@", dateTime);

// Convert to new Date Format
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
newDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateTime];

 NSLog(@" string Date is %@", newDate);

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

 //[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:newDate];

NSLog(@"date format date %@",dateFromString);
```

Comment: what is dateTime ?

Comment: it's date and time- Thu Jan 25 10:38:11 2018

Comment: Can u send your dateTime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting NSString to NSDate (and back again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917250/converting-nsstring-to-nsdate-and-back-again)

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert dateFormat as per date is coming and after convert it as you want.

Try this below code..

```
NSString *dateTime = @"Thu Jan 25 10:38:11 2018";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTime];
    NSLog(@"Date is %@", dateTime);
    // Convert to new Date Format
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
    NSLog(@"result %@",result);
```

Comment: @ishant you can get 10:38:11 in string format in result string

Comment: @ishant means you need this same output in `NSDate` format ?

Comment: Yes i need same output

Answer (score 0):

Split the time in date components and use that components as a time.

Check below code.

```
NSString *aStrTime = @"10:27:43";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:aStrTime];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:date];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
NSInteger sec = [components second];

NSLog(@"%d:%d:%d", hour, minute, sec);
```

**Note:** change `aStrTime` and `dateFormatPattern` according to your need.

Comment: i need to use in local notiifcation. how can i use integer format.

Comment: @ishant For local notification, along with the time you have to specify the date (as NSDate) to `fireDate`.

Comment: No but i need on time. on local notification. if i will set with time it will show on selected day only. but i need everyday on same time.

Comment: @ishant for that you need to set `repeatInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try the following code:-

For e.g:- if you are getting the date in 10-02-2017 12:30:50 format

NSString *strDate = @"10-02-2017 12:30:50";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];
NSLog(@"The Date is: %@", date);

// By this code you will get the date in NSDate form. Now you can change the format to get the time

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *strFinalTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:strDate];
NSLog(@"strFinalTime: %@",strFinalTime);
```