# How to print name of the day of the week?

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar, nsdatecomponents

Im trying to print out the name of the day of the week i.e Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday. I currently have this bit of code that does just that. I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of my switch statement and make this better. Thanks!

```
 func getDayOfWeek(_ today: String) -> String? {
    let formatter  = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    guard let todayDate = formatter.date(from: today) else { return nil }
    let myCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let weekDay = myCalendar.component(.weekday, from: todayDate)

    switch weekDay {
    case 1:
        return "Sunday"
    case 2:
        return "Monday"
    case 3:
        return "Tuesday"
    case 4:
        return "Wednesday"
    case 5:
        return "Thursday"
    case 6:
        return "Friday"
    case 7:
        return "Saturday"
    default:
        return ""
    }
}



getDayOfWeek("2018-3-5")
```

This prints out "Monday"

Comment: i'm not sure but maybe you should put 2018-03-05 instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong date format. The correct format is `"yyyy-M-d"`. Besides that you can use Calendar property weekdaySymbols which returns the weekday localized.

```
func getDayOfWeek(_ date: String) -> String? {
    let formatter  = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-M-d"
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    guard let todayDate = formatter.date(from: date) else { return nil }
    let weekday = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).component(.weekday, from: todayDate)
    return Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols[weekday-1] // "Monday"
}
```

Another option is to use DateFormatter and set your dateFormat to `"cccc"` as you can see in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27369380/2303865):

```
extension Formatter {
    static let weekdayName: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "cccc"
        return formatter
    }()
    static let customDate: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter  = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-M-d"
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return formatter
    }()
}
extension Date {
    var weekdayName: String { Formatter.weekdayName.string(from: self) }
}
```

---

Using the extension above your function would look like this:

```
func getDayOfWeek(_ date: String) -> String? { Formatter.customDate.date(from: date)?.weekdayName }
```

Playground testing:

```
getDayOfWeek("2018-3-5")  // Monday
Date().weekdayName        // Thursday
```

Comment: This actually is working! What If I don't want to use "locale"? Can I remove that line?

Comment: @user7097242 the locale is important if you are using a fixed date format.

Comment: Ok what is [weekday-1]? is that a hack or something?

Comment: weekdaySymbols returns an array. The first index is 0 so you need to subtract 1

Comment: but that doesn't make to much sense since weekday returns value from 1-7 no? There is no 0?

Comment: the array contains 7 elements. The first is Sunday at index 0 and the last is Saturday at index 6. weekday returns 1 for Sunday and 7 for Saturday thats why you need to subtract 1

Comment: For your second answer how can I do the same this as your first? Meaning how can I pass a string as a date instead of using a Date() object?

Comment: wow thats great stuff! It seems like its working on playgrounds. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
func DayOfWeek(date: String) -> String?
{
    let dateFormatter  = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-M-d"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    guard let _date = dateFormatter.date(from: date) else { return nil }
    let weekday = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).component(.weekday, from: _date)
    return Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols[weekday-1]
}
```