# iOS - Date prints the day before

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate

So i am trying to format a date(in string) and get the dat from it.

This is my code:

```
var cycleDate = "01.10.19"

func getDate(date: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yy"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from:date)!

    return date
}

func getCycleDay(date: String) {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    let myDate = getDate(date: date)
    let weekday = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: myDate)

    let stringwWeekday = dateFormatter.weekdaySymbols[weekday]
    print(date)
    print(myDate)
    print(weekday)
    print(stringwWekday)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    getCycleDay(date: cycleDate)

}
```

The prints are as follow:

01.10.19

2019-09-30 21:00:00 +0000

3

Wednesday

As you can see the date is not the correct one,
I check that the time zone and locale are as needed.

What is the issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your time zone is UTC+0300 the date is correct, `print` shows dates in UTC.

Comment: There is no issue. Your code is fine. See http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html

Comment: `print(date.description(with: .current))`

Comment: @LeoDabus the print as you say is working, yet as you can see the day of week is not good

Comment: @rmaddy so if it is fine why is the day of week not good?

Comment: you need to use `weekday-1`. Swift collection indices is zero based. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54728882/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus great!
Wanna post that as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I was only looking at the date part and not the weekday part. The weekday component is 1-based.